# How to get rid of extra confusing subdomain redirection?

Tags: redirect, domain

I've finished building my site just recently and I notice that when I open anything the url adds a nasty top subdomain to the top like in this example:

https://q-link.site/product/electric-longboard-motor-mount-adjustable/?v=88588bacf0da

(Referring to the "**/?v=88588bacf0da**" part)

Why does this happen and how do you get rid of it to see a cleaner domain?

Comment: WordPress isn't adding that, it's a popular plugin that does this

Comment: Ok which? why? and should you turn it off?

Comment: look at the banner saying the Question is a duplicate, and the linked to question, it contains the answer and an explanation from when someone else asked this

Comment: Yes the above topic is relevant and solved the problem thanks!